# Is it wrong as a Muslim to want to be God over my own creations in the afterlife?

Tags: halal-haram, allah, akhirah

I am completely invested in Islam and in no way seek to defy the commands of Allah and the teachings of his Prophet Muhammad (PBUH), but when reading about Jannah and how we will all be granted eternal happiness I was not very interested in the hori or rivers of honey, I would be more happy if I could become a God over my own creations; is it acceptable to think like this?

And will it ever be possible to become independent from Allah, or are we ever in his favour since he created us and without him we are nothing.

Comment: Wanting to be god or independent of god sounds very shirk-y.

Comment: I can understand in the case of being independant but what about being god? Care to expand ln your thoughts?

Comment: I'm sorry but have I found a [Light Yagami](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light_Yagami) here.... Anyway, in all seriousness if your desire to be God is embedded in a strong desire to own and control it can be beneficial to may be talk to some psychologist. Someone I know, used to be sort of like that, and the reason was that his life had become out of control and he desired to have total control on it

Comment: Also, being a Muslim means you have submitted yourself to God. If one wants to be a God of their own, then your are not really accepting submission to Allah anymore, and thus one won't really classify as a Muslim I think...

Comment: Oh ok thanks for the input, unlike your friend my desire is not that strong it was more a thought I had in passing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You can never be as strong as God. The want is baseless. It is also arrogant. In Islam, all the creation is inferior to Allah. So, it is wrong to want to be Allah. And there is a verse in the Quran that says people will be purified before they enter the heaven. So, I think people of paradise won't have such wish.

Answer (score 0):

Human have very limited powers and they do not have any form of perfections! Hence, if you think about it logically that we do not know most of the things that had been created and crafted within the universe. This world is definitely has a creator and human's duty is to worship and work hard (love each other and reserve God's creation) to earn the privilege of the gifts they had from Allah.